# How does PreviewView fill-scaling handle images which are higher resolution than the view?

Tags: android, androidx, android-camerax

When dealing with the `PreviewView` "FILL" scaling types (e.g. `PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER`), [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ScaleType) seem to imply that the image will not be scaled if it is higher resolution than the view.

> Scale the preview, maintaining the source aspect ratio, so it fills the entire `PreviewView`, and center it in the view

In cases where the image is lower resolution than the view, I can understand why the image is scaled, as otherwise there would have to be black borders (i.e. would not fill the entire view), which FILL is guaranteeing will not be displayed. In cases where the image is higher resolution than the view, the preview image already fills the entire view (i.e. doesn't need to show black borders) so my assumption would be that the preview does not need to be scaled.

For example, your image is 1920x1080 and your view is 800x800, I would expect `PreviewView` to not scale the image and just crop an 800x800 square out of the centre of the existing image (using `FILL_CENTER`).

However when looking into the code I could not find any condition which actually stops scaling from happening when the resolution is higher.

[For example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/camera/camera-view/src/main/java/androidx/camera/view/PreviewTransformation.java#191):

```java
        preview.setScaleX(surfaceRectInPreviewView.width() / mResolution.getWidth());
        preview.setScaleY(surfaceRectInPreviewView.height() / mResolution.getHeight());
        preview.setTranslationX(surfaceRectInPreviewView.left - preview.getLeft());
        preview.setTranslationY(surfaceRectInPreviewView.top - preview.getTop());
```

This code is after [all the matrix transformations are done](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/camera/camera-view/src/main/java/androidx/camera/view/PreviewTransformation.java#301) (which I don't fully understand), so I may be misinterpreting it. So I just wanted to validate my assumption about whether images are scaled if they are higher resolution than the view.

Answer (score 0):

PreviewView is designed to display the largest possible FOV. If you wish to display a smaller FOV, you can take a look at the zooming APIs: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl#setZoomRatio(float)

The scaling in `PreviewView` is for getting rid of the black bars in case the aspect ratio of the preview does not match the aspect ratio of the view. It doesn't matter what resolutions they have.

In your example, the output image is 1920x1080 and the view is 800x800. For the `FILL_*` types, the output image will be scaled to fill the view, in which case it will be scaled to 1422x800, then the extras will be cropped out. For the `FIT_*` types, the output image will be scaled to fit the view, in which case it will be scaled to 800x450, and placed inside of the view.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Your first paragraph is exactly the point I was trying to make. If the scaling is just to get rid of black borders (black bars) then why does the 1920x1080 image need to be scaled? It can be cropped and displayed in the view already without any black borders.

Comment: PreviewView is designed to display the largest possible FOV. If you wish to display a smaller FOV, you can take a look at the zooming APIs: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl#setZoomRatio(float)

Comment: okay, can you add that to your answer? as that's really what I was asking. I didn't find anywhere in the docs which stated that "PreviewView is designed to display the largest possible FOV", so this wasn't at all clear to me